# how can you use ! and && instead of ||?

Tags: javascript

How can you write an or function without using || operator? ! and && are permissible.

```
var output = or(true, false);
console.log(output); // --> true;
```

Comment: homework question, do I get credit if I help you solve? :D

Comment: Why would the value of `output` change by doing two `console.log`s?

Comment: You have to show your attempts to solve the problem. Otherwise your question has to be closed

Comment: @Ant Clearly the OP doesn't understand what he's asking. Ergo, homework question.

Comment: Look up boolean logic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's clearly homework, without stating so.

Comment: The true answer is `!(!a && !b)`. Simple tautology.

Comment: @Ant I have provided an `or` function does exactly the above request

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm no this was not a hw question. I genuinely just wanted to gain a better understanding so I am solving a lot of basic problems on my own. This is literally the first question I posted on stackoverflow only because I could not find a good explanation searching online. I am new to JS and I am sure you and everyone else here were a rookie at one point. So if you and others like you here are ethically motivated, a few words of advice and encouragement instead of down voting and belittling my question would definitely help me and those people like me more.

Answer (score 7):

There are two basic [tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) that you just have to combine. For any `a, b`:

1. De Morgan's law: `!(a && b)` if and only if `!a || !b`
2. Double negation: `!!a` if and only if `a`

Thus `a || b` if and only if `!(!a && !b)` so

```
function or(a, b) {
    return !(!a && !b);
}
```

---

That being sad this is only true if `a, b` are boolean. Note that `||` operator in JavaScript has side effect:

```
> var a = 'foo';
> var b = 'bar';
> a || b
'foo'
```

but

```
> !(!a && !b)
true
```

I doubt this can be achieved solely with `!` and `&&`. However this can be implemented without `||`:

```
function or(a, b) {
    if (a) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

---

This still is not 100% the same as `||`. That's because `a || b` evaluates `b` only if `a` is false. In particular for functions `f() || g()` the call `g()` will be evaluated only when `f()` is false. So this is another side effect of `||` which I don't think can be emulated by a function at all.

Comment: the more correct term is [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: @NinaScholz First of all there is no such thing as "more correct". Also the first one is De Morgan's law (which is a special case of tautology by definition) but the second one is not.

Comment: oh, no offence!

Comment: Genius answer, very logical and made my mind explode. Thanks for solving this kids homework.

Comment: De Morgan's law!  That was the name I was racking my brain for.  I was thinking, "Not _modus ponens_, not _modus tollens_..."

Answer (score 1):

When is `or` true?

Whenever either A is true or B is true -- but that answer includes the word "or".

So let's put it another way: whenever it is not the case that both A is false and B is false.

Answer (score 1):

```
!a && !b  =  !(a || b)

!a || !b  =  !(a && b)

!(a || b) =  (a || b) else
```

so to answer your question

```
!a && !b else  // this is the or
```

but that is a horrible thing to do.  Use positive logic and all the tools available to make your code readable.

Comment: The OP's instructor is trying to teach him logic, not good programming style.

Comment: What `!a && !b else` is supposed to mean?

Comment: The else condition is the inverter for a logical condition  iow !true else = true

Comment: What `inverter for a logical condition` means? You mean negation? How is that different from `!`? The real and simple answer is `!(!a && !b)`.

Comment: if (true) {} else {}  "else" responds to the inverted outcome of the condition.  In this example, it will respond to a false outcome.

Comment: I see where you are going, and yes, the simplified answer would be yours, but I was trying to teach something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking something like this?

```js
var a;
var b = 3;
console.log(a || b);

console.log(!a && b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I wanted to prove to myself the original question is entirely possible ;) and I didn't use a `|`

```js
function or(a, b){
    var c = console.log;
    console.log = function(input) {
        c.apply(console, [input]);
        window.output = !window.output;
    }
    return !(!a && !b);
}
// OP Question
var output = or(true, false);
console.log(output); // --> true;
console.log(output); // --> false;
```